# How to fix an error when starting the application NativeScript

Tags: xcode, vue.js, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Faced a problem when starting the application through "tns run ios". I can’t understand what the error is and what needs to be fixed, I will be glad of any help!
Running an application on Android runs without errors

[image from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNkd7.png)

```js
firebase.init({
  showNotificationsWhenInForeground: true,
  onPushTokenReceivedCallback: function(token) {
  },
  onMessageReceivedCallback: function(message) {
    console.log("Title: " + message.title);
    console.log("Body: " + message.body);
    // if your server passed a custom property called 'foo', then do this:
    console.log("Value of 'foo': " + message.data.foo);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you try to remove and add ios platform again? also what is nativescript version? you can follow this guideline to  https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions#upgrading-platforms

Comment: @MuhammadAli my nativescript version is 6.2.1 and remove and add ios platform did not helpю. The error remained

Comment: Where / How you are initiating Firebase plugin in your project? Share relevant code please.

Comment: @Manoj Hi! Added code to the body. Initialization occurs in app.js

Comment: Where do you call this method? If you remove this line does the error go away?

Comment: @Manoj If you delete this part, the error still remains.

Comment: Have you tried removing the hooks and node_modules folders, as well as the platforms?

Comment: Can you submit a sample repo where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @tigerdi yes, I deleted both folders, the problem remains.The application is launched with the tns run android command without errors, but when tns run ios starts, an incomprehensible error occurs for me and the application in the simulator shows only the launch screen and does not go any further

Comment: @Manoj made a test repo, I will be glad to any prompt by mistake: https://github.com/aschurf/mobiletest